Start Date Accuracy Report
I'm trying to write a formula to show that is an account starts in the same month or BEFORE it is predicted to start 1 else 0. We've done this with a +/- 7 day but I'm not sure how to do it for the month. Both Predicted Start Date and Start Date are fields. This is my original formula:
IF(SBQQ__Subscription__c.Start_Date__c-SBQQ__Subscription__c.Predicted_Start_Date__c<=7,1,0)

Some clarity is needed for how you're defining "same month". Do you mean that literally (predicted start date = 29th of June, actual start date = 30th of June, both in June so same month)? or in the sense of "within 30.416 days after the predicted start date"?

Why not just check if Start Date is greater or less than Predicted Start Date? Or do you only care if they started in an earlier MONTH? i.e., If they were predicated to start on 10/5/2024 but they start on 10/1/2024 do you not consider that an early start? It's only early if they start in an earlier month?

@DerekF  - yes, so if predicted start date is june 21st, we want to give them "credit" for anything that starts in June or an earlier month. July would not be credited at all.

@MorganMarchese we don't necessarily care if they started earlier, however, if they start within the month we are forecasting for. So if predicted to start  on 10/5 and they start on 10/20 or 9/20 they should still get "credit". However, if they start on 11/1 they would not get credit.

If what you care about is primarily comparing the start MONTH (assumed based on the statement: "show that an account starts in the same month or BEFORE"), then you'd want to use the MONTH function in your formula to extract the numeric Month from SBQQ__Subscription__c.Start_Date__c and SBQQ__Subscription__c.Predicted_Start_Date__c.
Then you could just check if the Start Date Month is less than or equal to the Predicted Start Date Month to return your 1 or 0.
IF(MONTH(SBQQ__Subscription__c.Start_Date__c) <= MONTH(SBQQ__Subscription__c.Predicted_Start_Date__c),1,0)

This is not a perfect formula, just an example. You'd also likely need to take YEAR into account to make sure that the formula works correctly for situations where the Start Date might be 1/1/2025 but the Predicted Start Date was 12/1/2024, etc. You could do this by also incorporating a YEAR function into your formula, checking if the YEAR on both fields match, or if they don't, adjust your logic accordingly to account for the different years.

This worked! THank you!!

Happy to help @Mimmy91, if this is for giving Sales Credit, please be sure to incorporate year logic into your formula as mentioned above. Otherwise you might have some accidental credit given for subscriptions started around end of year. Also it's appreciated to mark this as resolved if your issue is taken care of. Thank you!
